# Eclipse & Groovy - unable to resolve class

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I am new to groovy and eclipse. I am going through a few tutorials and one of them calls for a groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder class to be imported but I get the following error message "Groovy:unable to resolve class groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder". What am I doing wrong?

I have the following installed: 
- Eclipse (2019-09)
- Groovy Development Tools (3.6.0SNAPSHOT)
- Groovy Version: 3.0.0-rc-1
- JVM: 13.0.1

[image]
[image]

Comment: More information is needed. Update the question with a link to the tutorial you are using, and clearly state the point at which you hit the problem within that tutorial. A screen shot showing the actual error would also be helpful, so that others can attempt to replicate your problem.

Comment: Tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_xml.htm
Class appears to be missing. I have done the groovy installation exactly as has the tutorial under "Environment" and whilst they jump right into using XMLBuilder I appear to be missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download groovy sdk from https://groovy.apache.org/download.html

Add this jar file to your class path. It will resolve your issue.
Alternatively, You can unzip that jar and specifically add only the required groovy-xml-2.5.8.jar to your build path.